# Datatables columns

Tags: datatables

como puede concatenar dos registros en una sola columna en un datatable, hasta ahora solo lo hago con un registro, pero necesito hacer los con dos, esto con el fin de optimizar el espacio horizontalmente del datatable.

estoy haciendo algo asi:

```
columns: [
                    { 'data': 'C019fechaRegistro' },
                    { 'data': 'C019hora' },
                    { 'data': 'C019alertaIn' },
                    { 'data': 'C019alertaSup' },
                    { 'data': 'C019accionIn' },
                    { 'data': 'C019accionSup' }]
```

pero necesito juntas la fecha de registro y la hora en una sola columna. como puedo hacerlo.

Comment: Te refieres a hacer algo como: { 'data': 'C019fechaRegistro' + 'C019hora' },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera, concatenando los campos de tu `Datatable()`

```
columns: [
            { 'data': 'C019fechaRegistro'+' '+'C019hora'},
            { 'data': 'C019alertaIn' },
            { 'data': 'C019alertaSup' },
            { 'data': 'C019accionIn' },
            { 'data': 'C019accionSup' }]
```

Puedes hacerlo tambien con un render:

```
    columns: [
            {render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                    return data.C019fechaRegistro+' '+data.C019hora;
                    //return row[0]+' '+row[1];
            } },
            { 'data': 'C019alertaIn' },
            { 'data': 'C019alertaSup' },
            { 'data': 'C019accionIn' },
            { 'data': 'C019accionSup' }]
```

Comment: Me sale este error de la libreria datatables si lo hago de la manera que me sugieres...  DataTables warning: table id=tablaReportes - Requested unknown parameter 'C019fechaRegistro C019hora' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4 @Eduardo Javier Maldonado

Comment: @LuisMiguelViana actualice la respuesta, es mejor que utilices render para que no te genere problemas.

Comment: Si obtienes un error de **data**, utiliza **row**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, ya encontré la solución, es algo como lo mencionabas  ......... {"render":
        function ( data, type, row ) {
            return (row[3] + ' ' + row[4] + ' ' + row[5] + ' ' + row[6]);
          
        }
  },

Comment: @LuisMiguelViana perfecto, tal cual se trabaja con render, si te sirvió la respuesta no olvide marcarla como correcta, o simplemente valorarla.